# Транзакции и блокировки на чтение

Tags: php, mysql, yii, транзакции

Ситуация такая:

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
$condition=$model->getCondition(); //обычный select из кучи таблиц
if($condition) {
//... куча функций, апи вызовов, изменений баланса пользователя, в результате $model->getCondition() уже не вернет прежнего результата
}
$transaction->commit();
```

Но если юзер делает 10-100 запросов одвновременно, то код внутри "if($condition){}" будет выполняться несколько раз, что неприемлемо. 
Т.о., мне нужен лок на чтение внутри транзакции, так чтобы второй запрос пользователя ждал, пока завершится первая транзакция, и только потом получил ответ на запрос $model->getCondition() - уже обновленный ответ.
Я кучу всего перечитал из манов, и нашел только то, что нужно прописать "transaction-isolation = serializable" в конфиге мускла. Но это не помогло =(
Соответственно, вопрос: что делать?

P.S. таблицы innodb, конечно.

Comment: SELECT ... FOR UPDATE пробовали делать?

Comment: Пробовал. Не помогает. Так же, если несколько раз быстро кликнуть, то удается выполнить код внутри if 2 раза.

Comment: Как один из вариантов можно рассмотреть блокировку таблиц `LOCK TABLES` перед началом выполнения всех операций и их разблокировку после. Но есть существенный минус, на чтение будут лочится запросы всех пользователей.

Comment: А есть ли возможно блокировать только те строки, которые участвуют в запросе (пуст даже они из нескольких таблиц, с использованием group и т.п.)? И можно ли как-то автоматизировать этот процесс? Т.е. я не всегда знаю, к каким таблицам идет обращение внутри транзакции, и чтобы мне не шерстить весь код, а просто прописать что-то вначале?

Comment: И да, почему не работают транзакции как они должны работать? Вроде как изоляция serialize должна делать именно то, что мне нужно, нет? Почему не делает?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут проблема не в изоляции транзакций на базе. 
Если запросы идут одновременно, то несколько селектов (столько, сколько есть коннекшенов к базе) будут запущенны одновременно, и они все принесут результат неизменненой еще базы. Соотвественно условие выполнится, и они все одновременно начнут изменять базу. Для того, чтобы этого избежать, надо применять двойную блокировку с ручным локом (можно на базе, можно в памяти). После проверки кондишена поток должен пытаться захватить лок (какой-нить уникальный ресурс, монитор), и потом проверить получилось ли. и только если да, то продолождать работу по изменению данных, не забыв в файнели освободить уникальный ресурс..

Comment: Понял, благодарю) Странно, что такая банальная проблема должна решаться таким костылем. И, вроде как, select for update специально создан для подобного, но не справляется.

Comment: А чему тогда верить? БД верить нельзя. Потому что раз select может выполниться одновременно, не смотря ни на какие lock tables, транзакции, select for update и т.п., то и селект лока точно так же будет лажать. Хранить отдельный лок файл (для каждого юзера\каждой требующей лока операции) - это идиотизм, таких файлов должно быть десятки тысяч. И, как показывает практика, раз  в несколько месяцев что-то падает и лок виснет. Остается сессии? Но тоже неизвестно, как они одновременно сработают. Либо разворачивать redis или что-то в этом духе. Больше вариантов нет?